# Create hyperlink in Javascript in message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am displaying error validation message in a input box when input value is more than expected.

Example - If input value is more than 1000, error popover says - "some text to be displayed".

```
messages:{
thisIsAnInputid:{
    number: 'some message',
    min: 'some message',
    max:'some message',
    required:'some message **Need hyperlink here**'
    },
    ...
    ... }
```

I am displaying this message as a rule of message in my javascript file with input ID. I simply want to add a href here so that User can click on the error message to redirect to another Page.

Thanks,

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: `if (confirm("Input value is more than 1000\nDo you wish to see more information about why this is wrong?")) location.replace("errormessage_morethan1000.html");`

Answer (score 0):

You could fire this function if the input value is more than 1000.

```js
function Alert() 
{
    var answer = confirm("Click ok to visit link.") // If they click okay, they visit the link.
    if (answer)
    {
        window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251325/create-hyperlink-in-javascrip-in-message/43251588#43251588"; // Change link here.
    }
}

Alert();
```